# In the Journey / On the Journey

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Buddhism, **In** the journey to peace

/

> Buddhism, **On** the journey to peace

How the "in" and "on" in this sentence differently mean?

Comment: Is it title of something ? like a  book or an article ?

Comment: I think you'd better provide more information, context or ..

Comment: With singular, I think it should be "on", with plural, more often "in".

Comment: Yes it's a title itself. Buddhism, in the journey to peace. And Buddhism, on the journey to peace. How does "in" and "on" differs the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: As far as I know, **on** or **about** is used for the title, where, **on** imply that , the contribution is completely dedicated to the aforementioned title. So, I would say, On the journey to peace

Comment: This is not a sentence. Thus it is hard to determine which would be more apt. Both are good grammatically.

Comment: A more common construction for a title would be "Buddhism, the journey to peace", implying that [the practice of] Buddhism *is* a journey to peace.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provaided details, could be the next:

- In = inside
- On = over, about

Further information: http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-in-and-on/

Answer (score 0):

It is "on the journey", see Oald. I think "on the journey" is analogue to "on the way". http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/journey_1?q=journey